# Reduce server requests made by AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a slider component which calls an AJAX request to update a table based on the values the slider is pointing too.

On my local server, not implementing a delay function seemed fine, but since deploying my code onto a cloud service I've noticed there is a significant amount of lag generated by the amount of requests sent to the server when a user is sliding.

My current code:

```
$( "#psi_slider" ).slider({
    range: "min",
    value:0,
    min:0,
    max:max_psi, 
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        update_results(json, get_values());
    }
});
```

Could anyone advise how I could implement a timer between requests, i.e. send a request every second?

Comment: In your case, what's the advantage of grabbing the data one at a time instead of everything you need on the first request?

Comment: My client specified the table must update as a user slides to provide a better UX, I did previously have the update bound to `changed:` but that wasn't good enough!

Comment: therefore, I need to implement some sort of delay, as the load sent to the server right now is huge.

Comment: only update on slidestop.

Comment: But the UX and the AJAX implementation do not need to be coupled. You could grab all the data up-front and implement your own timing mechanism to satisfy the UX.

Comment: @Diodeus thats my problem, I'm not sure how to implement a timing mechanism, when the page loads I grab all the data, put it into an array and then sort that array whenever the slider changes.

Comment: Don't send ajax on change. Do it on slideStop.

Comment: Yup - using slideStop now, it just loses the effect he wanted, think he's happy with the improved performance though. cheers all.

Comment: Couldn't you keep the effect, just don't actually push the data to the server until stop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This scenario is very similar to that in which a user types on a field and you want to update data/provide as the user types, but not necessarily every time that the user presses a key.

There are three approaches to this situation:

### Approach 1: update every single time that something gets changed

This can possibly be a doable approach when "something gets changed" means "the user presses a key" but definitely not when it means "the slider moves a tiny bit" which is your case.

```
...

whenSomethingChanges : function(){
    updateData();
}

...

function updateData(){
    // Make your ajax call
}
```

#### **Fiddle**

### Approach 2: wait until things stop changing, then update

That is, when the user stops typing or stops moving the slider for some time, update your data. In the case of the slider this approach suffice to drastically reduce the amount of Ajax calls. However, it has the obvious downside that, if the user does not stop moving things around, he/she will not see the results of his/her actions and may become frustrated.

```
var timeout = 500; // half a second
var scheduler = new Scheduler(updateData, timeout);

...

whenSomethingChanges: function(){
    scheduler.updateDataInAWhile();
}

...

function Scheduler(callback, timeout){

    this.callback = callback;
    this.timeout = timeout;
    this.updateDataTimeout = null;

    this.updateDataInAWhile = function(){

        if(this.updateDataTimeout){
            clearTimeout(this.updateDataTimeout);
        }

        var self = this;
        this.updateDataTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
            self.callCallback();
        }, this.timeout);
    };

    this.callCallback = function(){
        if($.isFunction(this.callback)){
            this.callback();
        }
    } 
}

function updateData(){
    // Make your ajax call
}
```

#### **Fiddle**

### Approach 3: update periodically while things keep changing

The title says it all. This will put a limit on the frequency Ajax calls while at the same time providing feedback to the user in a continuous manner.

```
var timeout = 500; // half a second
var scheduler = new Scheduler(updateData, timeout);

....

whenSomethingChanges: function(){
    scheduler.keepUpdating();
}

...

function Scheduler(callback, timeout) {

    this.callback = callback;
    this.timeout = timeout;
    this.currentlyUpdating = false;
    this.finalTimeout = null;

    this.keepUpdating = function(){
        if(!this.currentlyUpdating){
            this.startPeriodicUpdate();
        }

        if(this.finalTimeout){
            clearTimeout(this.finalTimeout);
        }
        var self = this;
        this.finalTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
                self.discontinueUpdates();
            }, this.timeout);
    };

    this.startPeriodicUpdate = function(){
        this.currentlyUpdating = true;        
        this.runPeriodicUpdate();
    };

    this.runPeriodicUpdate = function(){

        if($.isFunction(this.callback)){
            this.callback();
        }

        var self = this;
        if(this.currentlyUpdating){
            setTimeout(function(){
                self.runPeriodicUpdate()
            }, self.timeout);
        }
    };

    this.discontinueUpdates = function(){
        this.currentlyUpdating = false;
    };
}
```

#### **Fiddle**

Comment: Approach 3 was exactly what I was looking for.