# Reduce Ajax Requests ReactJS Slider

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I'm looking to implement [Accepted Answer Version 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24681024/reduce-server-requests-made-by-ajax/24684556) in React. Basically, instead of updating every time there is a change to the slider, it updates periodically. I currently have a solution that updates on every change..

```
class SliderForm extends React.Component {
  handleInputChange(e) {
    // run ajax request with e.target.value
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="range" value={this.props.value_to_update} onChange={this.handleInputChange.bind(this)} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [debouncing](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) your handler function, limiting it to executing only once within a certain timeframe.

Using [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/)'s [debounce](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) function you could try something like this:

```
class SliderForm extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        this.handleInputChange = _.debounce(this.handleInputChange.bind(this), 1000);
    }

    handleInputChange(e) {
      // run ajax request with e.target.value
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="range" value={this.props.value_to_update} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```